# discord.js say command help meeee

Tags: discord, discord.js

so im trying to put this in a .js file in my replit discord bot and it wont power up, any know how to fix it? this Is how i did my other things but it includes the prefix, and i don't want the prefix to show it, like, when someone says hi i want the bot to say for example hello back to him. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1ALq.png)

```
client.on("message", async message =>{
  if (message.content.startsWith("ce faci"))
  {
    message.channel.send(uite ma scarpinam la coaie)
  }
```

Comment: You say the client wont start, are you getting any errors? If so edit them in your question

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, go to the Discord Developer Portal (https://discord.com/developers/applications), click "New Application", give it any name you want, go to the left side of the screen and click on "Bot", and press the button "Add Bot", and press "Yes, do it!" to the pop-up. There should be a token that's been generated. Copy it and put it in the code template bellow.

```js
// Import discord.js and create the client
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client();

// Register an event so that when the bot is ready, it will log a messsage to the terminal
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
})

// Register an event to handle incoming messages
client.on('message', async msg => {

  // Check if the message starts with '!hello' and respond with 'world!' if it does.
  if(msg.content.startsWith("!hello")) {
    msg.reply("world!")
  }
})

// client.login logs the bot in and sets it up for use. You'll enter your token here.
client.login('your_token_here');
```

It might be helpful to use a guide, and you'll find plenty of them on YouTube that teaches you the basics of using Discord.js.

If this is your first time coding in JavaScript or coding in general, I'd suggest that you go on websites such as Codecademy, freeCodeCamp, Khan Academy, YouTube, W3Schools, etc. to learn the basics.